# cómo alternar los elementos de dos array list en una tercera lista en C#? Windows Forms (.NET framework)

Tags: c#

Se leen dos listas (ArrayList) de enteros. A continuación ordenamos esas dos listas.
Tendremos botones más: para crear una tercera lista mediante intercalación de las dos
anteriores. (Meteremos, a partir de las listas ordenadas, elemento a elemento en una
tercera lista).

No se pueden utilizar métodos (solo Message Box). Se debe usar programacion modular. Esto es lo que tengo:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ArrayList lista1 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList lista2 = new ArrayList();
        void AñadirNumerosLista1 (int num)
        {
            num = int.Parse(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Introduzca el número."));
            lista1.Add(num);
        }
        void AñadirNumerosLista2(int num)
        {
            num = int.Parse(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Introduzca el número."));
            lista2.Add(num);
        }
         void MostrarLista(string texto1)
        {
            texto1 = "Los elementos de la lista 1 son: ";
            foreach (int num in lista1)
            texto1 = texto1 + num + ", ";
            MessageBox.Show(texto1);

            string texto2 = "Los elementos de la lista 2 son: ";
            foreach (int num in lista2)
                texto2 = texto2 + num + ", ";
            MessageBox.Show(texto2);
        }
        void MezclarLista (string texto)
        {
            int i;
            int suma;
            suma = lista1.Count + lista2.Count;
            texto = "";
            for (i = 0; i < suma / 2; i++)
            {
               texto = texto + lista1[i] + ", " + lista2[i] + ", ";
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Estos elementos componen la tercera lista son " + texto);
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int num;
            num = 0;
            AñadirNumerosLista1(num);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int num;
            num = 0;
            AñadirNumerosLista2(num);
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lista1.Sort();
            lista2.Sort();
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string texto;
            texto = "";
            MostrarLista(texto);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string texto;
            texto = "";
            MezclarLista(texto);
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lista1.Clear();
            lista2.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que la tercera lista podría estar fuera de tus function, por lo cual cada vez que leas los elementos intercalados vayas agregando los elementos a la lista "general" y así mientras recorres ambas listas con un for each o for si te acomoda.

Comment: Yo no usaría la clase ArrayList, sino List(Of Type) que suele dar muy buenos resultados e implementa los interfaces IEnumerable(Of Type) e IEnumerable. Por otra parte, debes considerar que puede que las listas no tengan el mismo tamaño, por lo que, tras unos elementos alternados, puede que aparezcan los elementos de una sola lista.

Answer (score 0):

Asi podes mezclar las listas.

```
void MezclarLista(string texto)
    {
        int i;
        int suma;
        suma = lista1.Count + lista2.Count;

        int mayor = Math.Max(lista1.Count, lista2.Count);
        texto = "";
        ArrayList lista3 = new ArrayList(suma);

        for (i = 0; i < mayor; i++)
        {
            if (i <= lista1.Count)
                lista3.Add(lista1[i]);
            if (i <= lista2.Count)
                lista3.Add(lista2[i]);

            //texto = texto + lista1[i] + ", " + lista2[i] + ", ";
        }

    }
```